# /n doesn't display as line break

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

`/n` is not putting a break in my embed message. My code and the embed it sent is located below. Can someone help?

[image: image of embed]

The section of Code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `rules`)) {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`OFFICIAL SERVER RULES`)
    .setColor(0xCF40FA)
    .setDescription(`Official rules for the USA discord server. Last updated: 1st October 2018`)
    .addField(`**GENERAL RULES**`, `1.Swearing is allowed, But not targeted towards a person./n2. Be respectful to everyone in the server./n3. No form of racism./n4. No public arguments./n5. Anything not suitable for work if forbidden./n6. All conversations are limited to English./n7. Spamming or mass mentioning is strictly forbidden./n8. Keep messages in their respective channels./n9. Fake or bad links, advertising anything non-US related, stays out of this discord./n10. Keep bot commands in #bot-commands ./n11. No talking in #announcements .`)
    message.channel.send({ embed: embed });
  }
});
```

Comment: In case that's the only issue, it's backslash: `\n`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct escape character for newline is `\n` not `/n`.